# MongoDB aggregation caching strategy

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a huge time series collection with more than 200k rows of logs. A sample would be like:

```
{
  timestamp: ISODate("2015-10-09T23:06:37.000Z"),
  type: "foo",
  value: 2
},
{
  timestamp: ISODate("2015-10-10T23:06:38.000Z"),
  type: "bar",
  value: 150
}
```

Aggregating the raw entries is pretty straightforward, in most cases we want to process the log entries for a specific range:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$match: {'$and': [{
    'timestamp': {'$gte' : ISODate("2015-08-18T00:00:00.000Z")}},
    {'timestamp': {'$lte' : ISODate("2015-08-20T00:00:00.000Z")}}]}
  },
  ...
]);
```

Since we are facing performance issues I was wondering if there is any way to cache aggregated queries within a timespan in order to improve our performance metrics.

Is there any way to avoid aggregated calculations and transforms if there are already cached?

Shall we use rollup middleware collections with our aggregated data and populate them on runtime? Is there any caveats or patterns with this strategy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB indexes for increasing your query performance [Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)